# Do both of these create a namespace, or is there a difference?

Tags: javascript

```
var Blah = Blah || {};
```

or

```
if ((typeof Blah) == 'undefined') {
  var Blah = {};
}
```

Is there a difference or both do the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference. The first assigns `Blah` to `Blah`, but if `Blah` is a falsy value (one which typecasts to `false` in a boolean context, such as `NaN`, `undefined`, `0` and `''`), it'll set `Blah` to an empty object.

The second only sets `Blah` to an empty object if it is exactly `undefined`, as the only value with the `typeof` type `undefined` is `undefined`.

Also, you are creating just objects, not namespaces. Even the concept of namespaces in JavaScript is iffy at best; most of the time it is done by creating a self-calling anonymous function that exports some things into a global object and not others.

Answer (score 0):

The first will assign an object to `Blah` if the current value of `Blah` is falsey.

The second will assign an object to `Blah` if the current value is undefined.

JavaScript doesn't have any concept of namespaces. It is just a term used when a bunch of related code exposes all its public parts through a **single** global variable. Since both of these are empty objects, there is no namespace.